# Give span same width on Firefox as Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, safari

I am trying to get a span to be the same width on Safari and Firefox.

My code can be seen at: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Ec04kr7seJ#)

And looks like this:

```js
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-md-1">    
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5  text-center">
    <div>               
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="codeAddress()">
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></button>
      </span>
      <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your address" style="max-width:256px;width:256px;">
     </div>
<br>
           
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="button" id="useAddress" value="Use address" class="outnowButtonOnGrey" style="width:131px;" onclick="codeAddress()">
        <span style="padding-left:7px;padding-right:7px;max-width:28px;" class="text-center">or</span>
        <input type="button" id="getCurrentLocation" value="Current location" class="outnowButtonOnGrey" style="width:131px;"><!-- 139px padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5  text-center">  
    Some text
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">          
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried various combinations of max-width, width, min-width but cannot get the width of the span to be the same on Safari and Firefox.

On Safari I get the effect I want which is the two buttons aligning left and right with the input field above. On Firefox the buttons no longer right align.

Answer (score 0):

span is an inline element not a box elelment, width doesn't apply to elements with style "display:inline", button is style "display:inline-block" - that *can* have a width set. 
so set the width on the button.

Comment: I tried replacing the padding/width on the span with margins on the buttons but I still get a different spacing for Firefox and Safari ([bootply update](http://www.bootply.com/ZETdOLwEwI)

Comment: don't use `<span>` use `<div>`.

Comment: I have been advised elsewhere that one should use span for inline elements.

Comment: if you must, add the style `display:inline-block` to the span then you will be able to set a width.

Comment: Thanks Jasen. I can now set the width of the span but I am getting different actual widths on Safari and Firefox.